# R function to find the index of a value in an array nearest to a given value

Tags: r, indexing

I'm currently working on setting up a locator for some ECG plots in R. The idea is to click twice (locator(n = 2)) to get a minimum and maximum index for the x-axis to then zoom into detail on the ECG.

The issue is that I get two rounded values in the array `location_array` for the new field of values to plot (for x) but if I then try to use it with my dataframe containing my data `df` it's using the actual values of my x-axis input from the locator rather than the indexes of the values.

Long story short: How can I get the indexes of the values which are closest to my min and max of location_array?

```
    par(ask = TRUE)
      
    location_array <- locator(n = 2)
      
    location_array <- round(location_array$x) 

    attach(df)
  
    #need the indexes of the values closest to location_array[1] and location_array[2] of df$time
    df2 <- df[location_array[1]:location_array[2],]
```

Thanks and have great evening everyone
tholori

Comment: Is it possible to have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) ?

Comment: You want `identify()` not `locator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon my question, I solved it with:

```
 location_array[1] <- which.min(abs(my.dataframe$Zeit - location_array[1])) 
 location_array[2] <- which.min(abs(my.dataframe$Zeit - location_array[2]))
```